# Tensorflow CIFAR10 get_variable not initialize

Tags: tensorflow

I was tracing cifar10 sample code [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/cifar10/cifar10.py)
.And I got some question with the following code snippet

```
def _variable_on_cpu(name, shape, initializer):
 """Helper to create a Variable stored on CPU memory.
      Args:
        name: name of the variable
        shape: list of ints
        initializer: initializer for Variable

      Returns:
        Variable Tensor
      """
      with tf.device('/cpu:0'):
          dtype = tf.float16 if FLAGS.use_fp16 else tf.float32
          var = tf.get_variable(name, shape, initializer=initializer, dtype=dtype)
return var
```

var seems not to be initialized (neither with global_variables_initializer() nor var.initializer.run())
and it just run perfectly.

However the following test code will raise an error:

"FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value test/x"

```
import tensorflow as tf 
with tf.variable_scope('test') as scope:
    x = tf.get_variable('x', shape = [3, 4], initializer = tf.constant_initializer([0,1,2]))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
print(sess.run(x))
```

Does anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code you added at the bottom does not work because you have not initialized your variable. So just add initialization:

```
import tensorflow as tf 
with tf.variable_scope('test') as scope:
    x = tf.get_variable('x', shape = [3, 4], initializer = tf.constant_initializer([0,1,2]))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
print(sess.run(x))
```

Comment: Then why does the cifar10 sample code snippet above works? (It seems that "var" is not initialized either.)

Comment: @陳昱名 because it just defines a var without doing anything. Most probably it will complain when you run this function